# How respect acept: text/plain with nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

In http header there is a field named `accept`, so client can specify prefered format.
How can I configure `nginx` to return `markdown` page in case of plain text request and processed via some markdown implementation in case of html request?

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution (and the simplest way) would be through an internal redirect.  You would probably want these inside of an `error_page` `location`, so that it's only activated when the pages are otherwise not found.

```
error_page 404 = @404;
location @404 {
    if ($http_Accept ~ "text/plain") {
        rewrite ^ $uri.text-plain break;
    }
    if ($http_Accept ~ "text/html") {
        rewrite ^ $uri.text-html break;
    }
    location ~ \.text-plain$ {
    …
    }
    location ~ \.text-html$ {
    …
    }
}
```

This would not take into the account the priorities that are specified in the `Accept` header, and, also, the explicit example of "text/plain" and "text/html" might as well be somewhat useless in existing browsers — I'm not sure which user-agents would specify `text/plain` in their `Accept` header.

In the old days, `Accept` was useful for deciding whether to serve `.gif` or `.png` images, but not anymore nowadays — it is now deemed that all browsers have and always has supported png images, and sending the extra bytes in the accept header is not worth the extra traffic, so, for example, Mozilla no longer `Accept`'s `image/png` explicitly, and most other browsers probably follow suit, too.